# Are all the Assassin’s Creed games linear?

Tags: version-differences, assassins-creed-series

I  have been playing Assassin’s Creed Brotherhood. I am giving up because it is too linear. 
I don’t want to play the “Quests” involving a lot of jumping, or Desmond’s parts, but the game doesn’t give me an option.

Is the whole of A.C. series the same type of linear gameplay as in AC: Brotherhood?

I had originally intended to play other games of this series but will not if they are so rigid.

Don’t get me wrong, there are a lot of great things about the game, but I just can’t bother to follow directions and do lot of jumping (seems more Spiderman than assassins….).

So can you please tell me if the other installments of the game are also rigid in their story arc?

**EDIT** I chose to Abort Memory in a quest I din't want to do. I didn't receive a new quest, and the map icon for the aborted quest is still there, and if I go there it asks me to do the quest which I decline, but it stays my current mission.

I understood that this means that the story is linear and that I can't not do the quest (it is the find the temple in the underground wolf thing cult). I can cope with desmond but not this quest, is there a way to skip it?

Comment: One of the core gameplay mechanics revolves around parkour. If you don't like the jumping around, you're playing the wrong series. I would also recommend **against** starting with brotherhood. You'll be missing some important and interesting backstory from previous games.

Comment: I wouldn't consider any of the assassins creed games totally linear. Yes there is a definite flow of progression though the games, and you are required to complete the story mission you're on before progressing to the next one. But each game has it's array of side quests, activities, collectibles, and ability to explore the world. It is also my personal opinion that Brotherhood is the worst in the series (though I've heard bad things about 3), so you might find one of the other games more enjoyable.

Comment: To be precise, many games ofter open world, but it is a single player story based game. The main element has to be linear for the same reason you read a book in order.

Answer (score 5):

Hardcore Parkour is definitely a significant aspect of the AC series. It is definitely not as free as skyrim (where you get your mission goal, mission start, and do whatever you want on the way there, wherever, etc.), but at the same time, much less limited than many other games (not to name names). It has some activities that require you to follow a path fairly strictly, and some quest missions lead you around puzzles with one solution, and not much else around. However, the game itself is very much a free-roam game. You are quite encouraged to do missions wherever you find them, chase pickpockets, go wherever you want; and although some quests don't give you this option, if you need to get somewhere or kill somebody, you often have several options to not only choose from, but plan out; some more skillful than others!

The story-line is definitely progressive, but when considered, for the most part, it needs to be. (no spoilers) Some aspects of it could be switched around, but for the most part, you need to complete everything in chronological order. If the game was JUST the 1 quest, then it would be terribly linear and quite painful, but all of the parkour, exploration, and options make it satisfying.

In short, if you don't like parkour, its probably not the series for you. And if you are only completing the main quest/s, you are definitely not getting the thrill the series presents. But if you approach the game, trying to get the most out of it: you will probably enjoy it.

Also, keep in mind, while the game is meant to be open and enjoyed, it is also there to tell its own piece of a much larger story: and understanding and trying to piece together this story is a significantly important part of enjoying the game.